# RnR: Long running process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statusbar, background-process

I have a part of my application that creates an export file.  The export file process is fairly quick for the vast majority of users however, there are users that generate 10,000 or more records.  This complicates things.  First, the tool that imports the files, blows up on files larger than about 4,000 records.  Secondly, the process for 10,000 records takes about 20 minutes.  There has a tendency for the users to start doing other things and then for what ever reason, the process seems to time out and they never get their file.  However, if you click the process button, and just leave your machine alone, 20 minutes later you will get the file.

I need to make this more user-friendly and robust.  Here's my ideas:
1) automatically create separate files of 4,000 a pop
2) provide a status bar for the file generation
3) background the process so a user can click the button and come back say an hour later and download their files

So I have been doing research on the background plugins and gems.  Most seem to be fairly out of date, which make me nervous and may seem to be major overkill for what I need.  So Spawn seemed to be simple and straight forward but I'm unclear on how to do a status bar for that type of product.

Then we have something like Delayed_job.  This seems like it would work but also seems a little heavy but it does provide the hooks to generate some kind of status update.  Anyone have an example of this?  The README is a little light.

Another issue is the file generation, how do I get this multiple files to download?  Anyway, I can store the generated file for the live of the user session?

Finally, most of the solutions are looking like a major change, this issue is painful but technically works.  So the time that I am being allotted to solve it is minimal so I am trying to KISS.  Thanks for any help and or direction you can provide.

Comment: Having faced this with a current app generating reports for users, I retain an email address for the user, and generate the report file in a specific directory. On the server, there is a cron job which emails the report to the user. Clunky, I know, but it works. The users know when they generate the report they will receive and email with the report in 30 to 60 minutes. They are satisfied with that.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for background processing job I guess you must look for [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) it supereasy run on [redis](http://redis.io/) as  against delayed_job which poll your databases changes

as per gathering progress info I guess there bunch of resque plugin here one that can help you in the [quest](https://github.com/idris/resque-progress)

Lastly

`Another issue is the file generation, how do I get this multiple files to download? Anyway, I can store the generated file for the live of the user session?`

Not sure what you actually meant but if you wanted multiple file to download can zipping into one can help